# Best way to name media queries when there are 10 or 20 of them

Tags: css, media-queries

Many resources seem to prescribe the use of 3 or 4 media queries for most projects: smartphone/tablet/desktop/wide or small/medium/large/xlarge. However as a perfectionist developer I often need more refined control than that so more media queries in between these "canonical" breakpoints. But then how to name them other than by their actual pixel values? (which isn't good because if later on we want to change one of these values we'd have to do so throughout the whole project)

For now I name all breakpoints by their pixel values (see below). Any better idea?

[image: Image with many media queries]

Comment: You don't need this many, regardless of your counter-argument. The better idea would be to do exactly what you don't want to do, simply and get rid of many of them.

Comment: You should consider to make use of a fluid layout technique.

Comment: Although you may not want to use it, look at how Bootstrap is structured. You'll be able to understand how to use % widths and then only a *few* breakpoints to suit your site/design. There's honestly no need for *so* many points

Comment: This isn't perfectionism, it's more like _self harm_. How do you even manage this many breakpoints? You should consider @gearsdigital suggestion of using more fluid design techniques. Media queries are there to correct _certain things that can't be avoided otherwise_, not for pixel-precision (although you could do that, I'll give you that, its not a great idea).

Comment: I once had to do something like this when a client wanted the font size to be dependent on the width of the window, and not all browsers had `vw` yet. That wasn't pretty. Fortunately, those days are over.

Comment: @drake035 You should have a look around MDN's CSS section, you will find a treasure trove of things there. If you want to scale font-sizes nicely the `vw` and `vh` units are what you are looking for. Then you only need media queries for the exceptions. For example, if your general font-size is `Xvw`, then you can create minimum sizes using `@media all and (max-width:500px){ font-size: /* 500px ÷ 100 * X  */; }` and your max bounds as  `@media all and (min-width:1200px){ font-size: /* 1200px ÷ 100 * X  */; }` (you would need to calculate those, or use SASS/LESS).